# Blender 2.8 dimension and transform numbers are not making sense

Tags: transforms, scale, units, dimensions

I have a model of a car (I'm a blender noob), it is set to Metric, and things look good, in the image below you will see the tire is 0.669m in the Y dimension, that is about right, I then select transform and drag it about one tire length along the Y-axis, and blender says it has moved 23.8meters, not approximately  0.66m as I would expect

Why don't these numbers make sense?

To add to this, the measure tool seems to make sense, so it seems the location information is wrong. If I click on the headlight it says it is 82m along the y axis. and the rear lights -87 meters, so the location data thinks the car is 170 meters long while the measure tool makes it about 5 meters long.

But to move a part of the car I can't type in a distance in meters and have it move that far.

[image: Dimension and transform numbers are not making sense]

Comment: Could you upload your blend file? It would help if we could look through the various scene settings. You can upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and just edit the given code into the question

Comment: Umm, no I can't, I brought the main file, and don't have redistribution rights

Comment: You could delete all the contents and make a default cube. If the problem persists with the cube, upload that.